# Telnet refuses Connection

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets, telnet

Im setting up a spell check program and am having trouble with connecting to a server that houses the program. I do not know if it is a problem with the creation of a socket connection or how I am using the telnet client.

I have tested it on my own computer using telnet with the address 127.0.0.1 and port 3335 and it works okay. when I then try to test it to a linux server, telnet does not connect and either times out or refuses the connection outright.

For some background on when I try to connect to the linux server. I ssh into the server to run the program. I then run the program and then use telnet in another shell window to try and connect. I get the address of the server by using the command `nslookup mach_name`.

I will paste the code for the socket creation below incase it is a code problem in the program:

```
    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
       dequeue(); // to take junk values out of the queue
       // initialize all values
       pthread_mutex_init(&workLock, NULL);
       pthread_cond_init(&canTake, NULL);
       pthread_cond_init(&canPut,NULL);
       char *dict = NULL, *port = NULL;
       int newsockfd; // to create the socket conditions 
       struct sockaddr_in clienaddr; // to get the client info
       socklen_t clilen;
       pthread_t threads[NUM_WORKERS]; // for the thread id
       if(argc < 2){
           dict = DEFAULT_DICT;
           port = DEFAULT_PORT;
       } else {
           dict = argv[1];
           port = argv[2];         
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < NUM_WORKERS; i++) {
           pthread_create(&(threads[i]), NULL, (void *) &worker,NULL);
       }
       load_table(dict); // load the table 
       int listenfd, portno;
       struct sockaddr_in server;
       socklen_t srv_len = sizeof(server);
       listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
       if(listenfd < 0){
           perror("socket failed");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        // changes all the buffers to 0 
        bzero((char *) &server, sizeof(server));
        // changes the port into a number 
        portno = atoi(port);
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port = htons(portno); 
        //binds the port to the listenfd
        if(bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, srv_len)< 0){
           perror("bind failed");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        // waits for incoming connections 
        if(listen(listenfd,BACKLOG) < 0){
           close(listenfd);
           perror("listen failed");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        clilen = sizeof(clienaddr); 
        bzero((char *) &clienaddr, sizeof(clienaddr));
        // listenfd = getlistenfd(port); // get the listen fd

        while(1){
           newsockfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &clienaddr, &clilen); // accept a connection 
           pthread_mutex_lock(&workLock); // make sure only one thread can access the queue 
           while(size == MAXSIZE) pthread_cond_wait(&canPut, &workLock); // make sure main thread is put to sleep if there is no space for the queue
           enqueue(newsockfd); // add the socket to the queue
           pthread_cond_signal(&canTake); // signal that worker threads can take from the queue
           pthread_mutex_unlock(&workLock); // unlock so another socket can be added 
       }
       close(listenfd);
       return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```

Comment: Check the server's firewall.

Comment: If you got a timeout, the remote didn't respond, so either it doesn't exist or its firewall ignored you. If it refused, there was nothing listening at the target port.

Comment: @user207421 "*If it refused, there was nothing listening at the target port*" - that is only one of several possible reasons for a connection to be "refused". Other reasons include 1) the target port is open but its backlog of pending connections is full, and 2) the port is being blocked by an anti-virus/malware or firewall and it was not silent about doing so.

Comment: _Connection refused_ means you touched a port in the remote server that has no process listening on it for connections (vulgar _the port is closed_).  Having timeouts could mean (or not) that you have a firewall in between, but the other error means that you reached the destination and no process was waiting there for a connection to reach it.  Check the port number, and how the server is running.  Use `netstat -tan` in the server to see what ports it is listening on.

Comment: BTW, post complete, minimal and verifiable examples.  Your post is neither complete nor verifiable (as it is posted).  It should be compilable, at least. And it is not because it lacks (probably) some header file that we need to provide, will never know if that is the source of the problem.  Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question.